# Does E8 sphere packing proof use a computer

Tags: integer-lattices

Does the proof by Maryna S. Viazovska that the [E8 sphere packing is optimal](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04246.pdf) use a computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"?  It is clear from reading the paper that some computing is done to get some coefficients, but then a rigorous proof follows.  What's the question?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "require a computer". Does it require a computer or could it be done by hand? Should we call it a "computer-assisted proof" ?
Yes I see the coefficients near the end of the paper, they look like they require a computer.

Comment: I would guess so.  You could ask Doron Zeilberger.  If he says it's useless then you know no computer was involved.

Comment: I only did a quick scan, so maybe a I missed something, but there was nothing that required a computer that I could see. Yes, a computer was used to handle some calculations, but the result of those calculations can be reasonalby *checked* by hand. A computer-assisted proof is one where you supply an algorithm to the computer that will come to a conclusion that is too difficult to even verify by hand. If this were such a proof, the author would need to prove that the algorithm - if correctly implemented and producing a result - would produce a correct result. There is no such discussion here.